icmp probes failing after upgrading to 24.04 (prometheus / blackbox-exporter)
I have a desktop monitoring lots of devices via Prometheus. Mostly tcp_connect probes but some icmp (ping) probes.
I upgraded Ubuntu to 24.04 LTS and everything still works APART from the icmp probes which now always fail. A straight command line ping of the same IP returns success.
The logs show Unable to do unprivileged listen on socket, will attempt privileged" err="socket: permission denied" but I don't understand really what it means or why it's failing under Ubuntu 24.04 when a ping works. Can anyone offer any advice to fix or debug further?
Logs for the probe:
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.373812878Z caller=main.go:181 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=info msg="Beginning probe" probe=icmp timeout_seconds=9.5
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.373965744Z caller=icmp.go:91 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=info msg="Resolving target address" target=172.19.0.30 ip_protocol=ip6
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.373999349Z caller=icmp.go:91 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=info msg="Resolved target address" target=172.19.0.30 ip=172.19.0.30
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.374024623Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=info msg="Creating socket"
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.374072447Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=debug msg="Unable to do unprivileged listen on socket, will attempt privileged" err="socket: permission denied"
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.374125943Z caller=handler.go:120 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=error msg="Error listening to socket" err="listen ip4:icmp 0.0.0.0: socket: operation not permitted"
ts=2024-10-23T15:46:55.374155274Z caller=main.go:181 module=icmp target=172.19.0.30 level=error msg="Probe failed" duration_seconds=0.000273796


prometheus version 2.45.3
blackbox-exporter version 0.24.0

This may be the same issue as this unanswered issue on Prometheus github.
EDIT 1:
Going on the clue of "permission denied" I did some more searching and have now found that generally, only root or daemons can create ping sockets. By default it's set to groups between 0 (root) and 1 (daemons).
sudo sysctl -a |grep ping_group_range
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0   1

If I temporarily set to include the Prometheus group (137) then the icmp probes start working:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range="0 137"

Of course, I don't really want to set it to that range and still not sure why Prometheus (as a daemon) can't create a ping socket on 24.04 - e.g. I still don't know what has changed since I upgraded to 24.04

It's written in the readme of the blackbox exporter, that you need elevated privileges for ping to work in modern linux distributions (like Ubuntu 24): https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter?tab=readme-ov-file#permissions
I run the blackbox exporter with the group "blackbox_exporter", so I added the corresponding group id 1005: net.ipv4.ping_group_range="1005 1005"

@Nuramon thanks for the link, that makes more sense! I reverted my group change and did what you said: sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf added a line for the prometheus group in my case: net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 137 137 and then sudo sysctl --system to apply change. If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

o.k. so I "solved" this by adding the prometheus user to the daemons group:
sudo vi /etc/group
daemon:x:1:prometheus

Not sure if this is the correct way or entirely safe but it works so will stick with it unless someone adds more info!
I still don't know what changed in Prometheus versions or Ubuntu network setup with my upgrade to 24.04. I have not seen any similar issues reported other than the one I already linked in my question.
